# Using diff for two files and send by email

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have files like below. I use crontab every 5 min to check the files to see if the system's added one file, for example like this: `AIR_2015xxxxT0yyyyyyyy.cfg`. Then I need to use the `diff` command automatically between the last one and before the last one.

```
AIR_20151021T163514000.cfg
AIR_20151026T103845000.cfg
AIR_2015xxxxT0yyyyyyyy.cfg
```

I want to do this in a script like the one below:

```
#!/bin/bash
/var/opt/fds/
diff AIR_2015xxxxT0yyyyyyyy.cfg AIR_20151026T103845000.cfg > Test.txt

body(){
cat body.txt
}
(echo -e "$(body)") | -a Test.txt mailx -s 'Comparison' user@email.com
```

Comment: So ... what error do you get when you run your script?  Or are you just writing shell-like meta code and hoping others will do the heavy lifting?

Comment: @ghoti actually i think you didn't read my question very well i have many files coming every day and i want to use a diff command with the last file and before last time.

Comment: Most systems don't have a command `-a`, so that's going to give problems.  Your use of the `body` function is peculiar; you should probable be using something like: `mailx -a Test.txt -s 'Comparison' user@email.com < body.txt`.  But there's a lot more work to be done to ensure you pick up the latest previous file, rather than hard-coding that.  It's a little odd that you have a completely fixed body for the email message.  I'd also suggest using a date/time in the name of the file attachment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler my dear for email no issue i can get emails but my issue is diff i can't make it automatically for example after each modification compare 2 file last one and before last one

Comment: Please isolate your problem for us. You do not have a problem with mail, so your problem might be: 1) Not send the diff of the last two files when they are the same as the last time (hint: look at modification time or add something in a logfile) OR 2) How to compare dates (hint: ls -trl is wrong for filenames with spaces, using `if [ "${file1}" -newer "${file2}" ]` should be wrapped in a function).

Comment: thanks for your comment @WalterA i i say there is no issue with mail my only issue is how i user diff for example diff newest file oldfile >Test
newest file mean last file and old file mean before newest file 
diff AIR_2015xxxxT0yyyyyyyy.cfg AIR_20151026T103845000.cfg > Test.txt how i make diff automatically to run everytime that someone made change on above files!

Comment: Do the newest file names actually contain a sequence of x's and a sequence of y's, or are you looking for the latest file and the previous one, both of which have the systematic names?  Is looking at the numeric names sufficient to determine the most recent, or do we have to worry about a file with an 'older' name being modified more recently than a file with a 'newer' name? If the new file has x's and y's, what code is responsible for renaming it with the all-numeric name? Given the systematic names using ISO 8601 notation (more or less), the names in simple sorted order give the latest last.

Comment: thanks alot dear @JonathanLeffler i really appreciate your help and i tested it's working but one thing is it possible if file are change someone changed is it possible to send email after modification? and whats mean of || exit 1 ?

Comment: The `|| exit 1` ensures that if the script fails to `cd` to `/var/opt/fds`, it stops rather than analyzing files in some other random directory. That was the easy bit. I'm not sure that I understand what you're asking with the other part of your comment/question. To know whether a file has changed, you have to decide how you know its state previously. That might be the modification time of the file (but that's fungible), or its size, or you might look at checksum for the file. But you have to have some sort of record of the old modification time, size or checksum to know whether it's changed.

Comment: thanks @JonathanLeffler again for reply, about 2nd question yes when size will change how to compare both files and send email.

Answer (score 2):

Given a list of files in the directory `/var/opt/fds` with names in the format:

```
AIR_YYYYmmddTHHMMSSfff.cfg
```

where the letter Y represents digits for the year, m for month, d for day, H for hour, M for minute, S for second, and f for fraction (milliseconds), then you need to establish the two most recent files in the directory to compare them.

One way to do this is:

```
cd /var/opt/fds || exit 1

old=
new=
for file in AIR_20[0-9][0-9]????T?????????.cfg
do
    old=$new
    new=$file
done

if [ -n "$old" ] && [ -n "$new" ]
then
    diff "$old" "$new" > test.txt
    mailx -a test.txt -s 'Comparison' user@example.com < body.txt
fi
```

Note that if the new file has a name containing letters `x` and `y` as shown in the question and comments, it will be listed after the names containing the time stamp as digits, so it will be picked up as the new file.  It also assumes permission to write in the `/var/opt/fds` directory, and that the mail body file is present in that directory too.  Those assumptions can be trivially fixed if necessary.  The `test.txt` file should be deleted after it is sent, too, and you could check that it is non-empty before sending the email (just in case the two most recent files are in fact identical).  You could embed a time-stamp in the generated file name containing the diffs instead of using `test.txt`:

```
output="diff.$(date +'%Y%m%dT%H%M%S000').txt"
```

and then use `$output` in place of `test.txt`.

The test ensures that there was both an old and a new name.  The pattern match is sloppier than it could be, but using `[0-9]` or an appropriate subrange (`[01]`, `[0-3]`, `[0-2]`, `[0-5]`) for the question marks makes the pattern unreadably long:

```
for file in AIR_20[0-9][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]T[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].cfg
```

It also probably provides very little extra in the way of protection.  Of course, as shown, it imposes a Y2.1K crisis on the system, not that it is hard to fix that.  You could also cut down the range of valid dates by basing it on today's date, but beware of the end of the year, etc.  You might decide you only need entries from the last month or so.

Using globbing is generally better than trying to parse `ls` or `find` output.  In this context, where the file names have a restricted set of characters in the name (no newlines, no blanks or tabs, no quotes, no dollar signs, etc), it is feasible to use either `find` or `ls` — but if you have to deal with arbitrary names created by random end users, those tools are not suitable.  (The `ls` command does all sorts of weird stuff with weird names and basically is hard to use reliably in the face of user cussedness.  The `find` command and its `-print0` option can be used, especially if you have a `sort` that recognizes `-z` to work with null-terminated 'lines' and an `xargs` that supports `-0` to handle such lines too — but you have to very careful.)

Note that this scheme does not keep a record of the last file analyzed (so if no new files appear for an hour, you might send a dozen copies of the same differences), nor does it directly report on the file names (but using `diff -u` or `diff -c` would include the file names being diffed in the output).  Again, these issues can be worked around if that's appropriate (and it probably is).  Keeping the record of which files have been compared is probably the hardest job; even that's not too bad:

```
echo "$old" "$new" >> reported.diffs
```

to record what's been processed; then

```
if grep -q "$old $new" reported.diffs
then : Already processed
else : Process $old and $new
fi
```